# Is there a way to rename the categories of the legend?

Tags: powerbi, formatting, rename, legend, legend-properties

I'm looking for a way to change the name of the legend of the graph without changing the data?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey, did my post answer your question? If so, would you mind accepting and upvoting the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do this directly in the format page. You'll either have to create another column that contains a user-friendly name for your data. Then use that as the legend.

Ex.

```
Legend = SWITCH(
    TRUE, 
    Table[Lag Days] <= 3, "Low", 
    Table[Lag Days] <= 7, "Medium", 
    Table[Lag Days] <= 30, "High", 
    "Extreme"
)
```

Or maybe use [grouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-grouping-and-binning) to create the legend names that you would like.